# call get methods for different classes behind one another

Tags: java

I have a class with name "ConstituentSet". it has one method namely "getNucleusInConstSet()" which the output will be from "Proposition" class . The new Class "Proposition" have another method namely "getProperty()". I want to know what is the Propertry of my "Proposition Nucleus" in class "ConstituentSet". but i do not know how can i do that.
I wrote as follow but It does not work.  `(ConstituentSet.getNucleusInConstSet()).getProperty())`

```
public class ConstituentSet{  
    // Constructor   
    private Proposition nucleusInConstSet;       

    public Proposition getNucleusInConstSet() {    
       return nucleusInConstSet;  
    }  
}  



public class Proposition{       

   //Constructor       
   private Property property;       

   public Property getProperty() {  
     return this.type;  
   }  
}
```

Comment: What happens when you call it that way? Do you get any error?

Comment: Question: why does getProperty return this.type and not this.propperty?

Comment: I get this error: "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getNucleusInConstSet() from the type ConstituentSet"

Answer (score 4):

You have:

```
(ConstituentSet.getNucleusInConstSet()).getProperty()
```

But you need to call an *instance* of `ConstituentSet`

e.g.

```
ConstituentSet cs = new ConstituentSet();
cs.getNucleusInConstSet().getProperty();
```

Note that this idiom (chained method calls) can be a pain. If one of your methods *returns* null, it's difficult to understand which one it is (without using a debugger). Note also that invocations of the form `a().b().c().d()` are a subtle form of broken encapsulation (`a` reveals that it has a `b`, that reveals it has a `c` etc.)

Answer (score 3):

if you type `((ConstituentSet.getNucleusInConstSet()).getProperty())` you are attempting to call a static method of `ConstituentSet`.

You need to instantiate it and then call on that object.

```
  ConstituentSet anInstanceOf = new ConstituentSet();
  anInstanceOf.getNucleusInConstSet()).getProperty());
```

Comment: Also, don't forget to set a value into `nucleusInConstSet` before calling `getProperty()` or you will get a NullPointerException

Answer (score 2):

This won't work:

```
ConstituentSet.getNucleusInConstSet().getProperty();
```

Because the `getNucleusInConstSet()` method is not static. You have to use an *instance* of `ConstituentSet`, something like this:

```
ConstituentSet cs = new ConstituentSet();
cs.getNucleusInConstSet().getProperty();
```

Of course, you have to make sure that `nucleusInConstSet` is not null, or you'll get a `NullPointerException`. Initialize its value in `ConstituentSet`'s constructor or set it using `setNucleusInConstSet()`.

Alternatively, you could make `getNucleusInConstSet()` static, but I don't think that's the right thing to do in this case (but we don't have enough information about the problem to say so).